# different login pages in root web.config file for authentication

Tags: asp.net

how can i specify two different login pages in root web.config file since i need to have authentication for two folders.for securing My Account module i did like this in the root folder

i need to have it for another folder called EBox also.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is similar to the following one (which has an approved solution):

[How to override/change FormsAuthentication LoginUrl in certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748287/how-to-override-change-formsauthentication-loginurl-in-certain-cases)

Hope this will help you.