# Membership providers - How to change programmatically the default page for Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership

I am using C# and .Net I need to redirect a user to a specific URL when the authentication (using Membership providers) failed.

I was thinking to use

```
RedirectToLoginPage(String)
```

From MSDN: Redirects the browser to the login URL with the specified query string

But I need to change the URL.

Example of use:

```
 if (!Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
    {// do smt here}
```

Any other idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this really works

aspx:

```
Username: <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUserName"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Password: <br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" onclick="btnLogin_Click" 
    style="height: 26px" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string username = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
   string password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

   if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
   {
     //...             
   }
   else
   {
       Response.Redirect("Hello.aspx");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When posting the credentials for checking the validity of the user, also pass a "return-to-url" query param or something. And in the logic behind, programmatically check the validity of the user and if the user is authenticated successfully then redirect to the given URL, or in your case, if the authentication failed, then redirect to a certain page.

One other thing you could do, since you want to redirect if the authentication failed, is to handle the 401 http status that results from a failed authentication client-side and redirect to the page you want from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/749257/1495554 there is no way to use standart methods to do like you want, @ZedBee wrote correct solution