# Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, form-authentication

FYI - This is not MVC.

I am using web form authentication and have the following in my web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/en/Admin/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="/DashBoard" />
</authentication>
```

I am also using Routing for bilingual/culture.

My route looks like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
    routeName, "{lang}/Admin/Login", "/Admin/Login.aspx", true, defaults, constraints, dataTokens);
```

If a user tries to access a restricted page they will be redirected to /en/Admin/Login based the value in the web.config.  My problem is if a user is viewing the site in french, the page is redirected to the English log in page when it needs to redirect to /fr/Admin/Login.

Is there any way around this as the entire site needs to be bilingual?

Comment: I found a similar issue with a few work arounds, but no true solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356982/how-to-redirect-to-a-dynamic-login-url-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar issue with a few work arounds, but no true solution.
[How to redirect to a dynamic login URL in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356982/how-to-redirect-to-a-dynamic-login-url-in-asp-net-mvc)

**Here's my solution:**

1) I added a session variable to keep track of what language the user has selected. 
(Ex: Session["lang"] = "fr")

2) I made my login page /admin/default.aspx in the web.config like below:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="/en/DashBoard" />
</authentication>
```

3) In my page load event for /admin/default.aspx I determine what language is set and redirect to the actual login page using the language from the session.

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        // Redirect to dashboard
        ...
    else
    {
        string returnUrl = "";
        if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
            returnUrl = "?ReturnUrl=" + Request.QueryString["returnUrl"].ToString();

        string selectedLanguage = "";
        if (Session["lang"] != null)
            selectedLanguage = Session["lang"].ToString();
        else
            selectedLanguage = "en";

        string loginURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth.LoginUrl"].ToString();
        loginURL = loginURL.Replace("{lang}", selectedLanguage);

        Response.Redirect(loginURL + returnUrl);                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the default (en//admin/login) page, parse the referring URL and redirect as needed.  (Assuming locale is determined on your site by the culture marker in the URL path.)  Eg,

```
var referrer = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(referrer))
{
    if (!referrer.Contains("/Admin/Login"))
    {
        if (referrer.Contains("/fr/")) Response.Redirect("/fr/Admin/Login");
        else if (referrer.Contains("/de/")) Response.Redirect("/de/Admin/Login");
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Of course that could be improved/simplified by using a regular expression to parse the referrer and checking against valid locales.

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer is always null.  I'm not sure that this is the best solution.  Seems like a hack.

Comment: @PsychoDUCK hmm, interesting.  Makes sense though I guess, since the original auth redirect is internal to the application.  I think you could still use the same approach by using the RedirectUrl in the query string, instead of the URL referrer.  Admittedly kind of a hack, but it seems like the best solution given your setup.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, on a better approach.