# How to add two different login url in form based authentication in C# MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, custom-authentication

I have one login page for admin, another login page for general user. I have created a custom membership provider for general user section, now I want to give form authentication in web.config file. How to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356982/how-to-redirect-to-a-dynamic-login-url-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not set two login urls for login inside webconfig file.If we create our own custom Membership provider, we have to set it as defaultprovider for making the [Authorize] attribute workable for it. But in my case, there were two providers. Both are custom providers, and I wasn't allowed to change the default provider. One provider is used for Admin login(the default provider), another provider used for user login (custom provider). In web config form authentication was enabled

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

So, when I was using [Authorize] attribute, it was taking  me to the admin login page and it is expected. But I needed an attribute which would take me to user login page. So I created a [AuthorizeUser] attribute which is now taking users to user login section.

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var username = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        if (username != "")
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" }));
        }
    }
}
```

This attribute is taking my users into user login page at ~/login

Answer (score 1):

When i work with custom membership provider, i also configure custom role provider and then add the following lines into my web.config file. You can see if it supports your scenario.

Step 1:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>

<membership defaultProvider="YourCustomMembershipProviderName">
   <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="YourCustomMembershipProviderName" type="Logger.SampleApp.Security.Infrustructure.CustomeMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="YourConnectionStringName" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="Logger.SampleApp.Client.Web"/>
   </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="YourRoleProvider"
    <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="YourRoleProvider" type="Logger.SampleApp.Security.Infrustructure.CustomRoleProvider" />" 
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Step 2:

Add `[Authorize]` attribute to Index method of HomeController.

Step 3:

under the `<appSettings>` section:

```
<add key= "enableSimpleMembership" value= "false"/>
<add key= "autoFormsAuthentication" value= "false"/>
```

Step 4:

Comment on `InitializeSimpleMembership` from `AccountController` and override login action as per requirement.

Comment: It was very helpful when I was creating custom provider. Thank you @sarmin